# Android Battery usage profiling

Tags: android, performance

Is there any way to profile the battery usage by the application in development environment or real time?
[BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) seems not providing any per application API

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that is possible at the moment.

There is a private API, PowerProfile, for retrieving battery consumption on a subsystem level (see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/os/PowerProfile.java). Also take a look at the code for the fuel gauge you find in Android's settings on how they calculate power consumption: http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ohAXAHj6Njg/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/PowerUsageSummary.java

Comment: Unfortunately, these links are all dead.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new tool called "[little eye](http://www.littleeye.co)" that does this.

It can profile Battery, CPU, Wifi and Data usage for an App in a development environment. Its a commercial product, but in beta right now, so free to download (for the moment). (disclaimer: I work at little eye)

http://www.littleeye.co

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product. (The product's website lists you as a member of the team)

Comment: I saw your website and ofcourse I found it very interesting. But your site says: Little Eye is not accepting new signups right now! Where can I find your tool or a trial version of it?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [Trepn Profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/increase-app-performance/trepn-profiler) by Qualcomm. Its features are:

- Profile device, or a single app
- Display battery power
- View CPU and GPU frequency and utilization
- Display network usage (cellular and Wi-Fi)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the two classes: `IBatteryStats` and `BatteryStatsImplernal` in package `com.android.internal`, they provide methods to get the statistics of battery usage.

Comment: These aren't available under normal circumstances. Do you know any workarounds? I've heard reflection mentioned, but don't know how I'd do it.