# per process power consumption in Android

Tags: android, power-management

Is there a way to see the power consumption of an Android process? I have a rooted HTC Hero, and I have developed some native programs in C language. I want to see the power consumptions of these programs. So, I want a way to measure the power consumption in process level and not in application level as e.g. PowerTutor application does..

Is there an API that can help me develop an application that can do this thing?
Can I use /proc/ stats etc.?

any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[AppScope](http://css3.yonsei.ac.kr:5612/appscope)** is an application energy metering framework for Android smartphones using kernel activity monitoring. AppScope provides an accurate and detailed both *per-application* and *per-process* energy estimation solution.

The current release supports HTC Nexus One only and can be found [here](http://css3.yonsei.ac.kr:5612/appscope/wiki/Downloads).

For more information and technical details about the AppScope framework you can read the AppScope paper presented at [USENIX ATC '12](http://www.usenix.org/conference/atc12), [here](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/atc12/atc12-final171.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

As said here: [Android Battery usage profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152447/android-battery-usage-profiling)

> There is a private API, PowerProfile,
>   for retrieving battery consumption on
>   a subsystem level (see
>   http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/os/PowerProfile.java).
>   Also take a look at the code for the
>   fuel gauge you find in Android's
>   settings on how they calculate power
>   consumption:
>   http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ohAXAHj6Njg/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/PowerUsageSummary.java

Comment: If it's correct please mark it to incentive people's answers ;-)

Comment: Yes, don't worry! I will do it as soon as possible I find that it's correct! :)

Comment: `BatteryStats` doesn't provide per-process power consumption estimation. Moreover there are many other disadvantages: update rate problem, information granularity problem and the fact that is implemented in Java (It's a Java class).