# How to calculate power consumption of android app?

Tags: android, performance

Whether there is any formula ,Api or method for it?
I want to test the power consumption of different apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [per process power consumption in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051807/per-process-power-consumption-in-android)

Answer (score 6):

Using adb tools you can view power consumption of each running app

```
adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo
```

sample output

```
Load: 1.12 / 1.07 / 1.01
CPU usage from 11344ms to 1613ms ago:
  10% 122/system_server: 5.8% user + 4.5% kernel / faults: 989 minor
  0% 233/com.htc.android.wallpaper: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 910 minor
  0.8% 271/com.htc.launcher: 0.8% user + 0% kernel / faults: 832 minor
  0% 40/panel_on/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 8/suspend: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 54/synaptics_wq: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0.2% 57/w1_bus_master1: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
  0% 253/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
  0% 13/kondemand/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 56/curcial_wq: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 2879/com.htc.bg: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
  0% 2904/dhd_dpc: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 2906/com.google.android.apps.maps:NetworkLocationService: 0% user + 0% kern
```

Using [batterystats](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys.html#battery) you can view each app's battery usage and power consumption:

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats
```

To list all available dumpsys tools:

```
adb shell dumpsys -l
```

*To configure adb tools:* http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Comment: Disadvantage of this method is that it doesn't work on the phone itself from an app.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer true, can not run from app it self check https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493463/1025070

Answer (score 1):

In order to analyse the power consumption, e.g. to estimate the mAh usage, checkout:

To see what's happening live (wakelocks, cpu, sensors, etc.):

- [API 26+] the [Energy Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/energy-profiler)* - modern UI included in Android Studio

[image]

To see what happened over time, e.g. this day:

- [API 21+] the [Battery Historian](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html) - in combination with [Dumpsys Battery](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys.html#battery). See their [github project](https://github.com/google/battery-historian) for instruction. Hovering the battery level chart (black in the screenshot) gives you the discharge rate in mAh when your phone was *not* charging.

[image]

*I haven't found out yet if it's possible to see an estimated mAh consumption instead ob abstract "low, mid, high" units in the Profiler. Comment please if you do so. The Historian should be able to do so based on the documentation.*