# Battery usage profiling in android

Tags: android, power-management

Hi, I want to know how much battery is being used by each and every component in my Android device how can we do that.

For example, assume a certain amount of the battery is being used by media player and determine how much battery is being used by a phone call at the same time

How can this be done programmatically?

I've have already checked what [this says about the private API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152447/android-battery-usage-profiling)

However, it doesn't work for me.

Can anyone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how much battery is being used by each and every component in my Android device how can we do that.

Buy a Qualcomm MDP and use Trepn to measure power usage by your application.

Beyond that, there are no means of doing this, sorry.

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply,[please check this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.lepeng.batterydoctor&hl=en) package name is net.lepeng.batterydoctor/.MainSettingsActivity
the thing i am trying is possible and there may be few use of this thats why my manager wants me to implement this,

Comment: after instaaling this app you can see TalkTime(3/4g) all 6 componts of list are required for my app.
please help me with that

Comment: and once again thank you very much for replying :)

Comment: if you can help me with progress bar of this app whose back ground is an image please help that how can we achieve this kinda of progres bar in android 
Thank you

Comment: @user1346836  u resolved ur issue ? can u pls share?