# How can I measure or get battery consuming statistic of application from android system?

Tags: android

I need to measure power consuming of application. Is there a some way to get it directly from android system? I also want to send this statistic on server so I need to do it periodically on run time.

Comment: Probably duplication of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051807/per-process-power-consumption-in-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Battery usage profiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152447/android-battery-usage-profiling)

Comment: Maybe it is, but answers and questions is too old and links doesn't work also.